# Problem in setting up boost library on ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost

I have compiled and installed my boost library in '/media/data/bin' in ubuntu 9.10.
And I have setup the INCLUDE_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH env:

```
$ echo $INCLUDE_PATH
/media/data/bin/boost/include:
$ echo $LIBRARY_PATH
/media/data/bin/boost/lib:
```

But when I compile the asio example, I get the following error:
$ g++ blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp

```
blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp:13:26: error: boost/bind.hpp: No such file or directory
blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp:14:31: error: boost/smart_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp:15:26: error: boost/asio.hpp: No such file or directory
blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp:16:28: error: boost/thread.hpp: No such file or directory
blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp:18: error: ‘boost’ has not been declared
blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp:22: error: ‘boost’ has not been declared
blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp:22: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp:24: error: variable or field ‘session’ declared void
blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp:24: error: ‘socket_ptr’ was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is wrong with

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
```

after which you don't need to set any `-I` and `-L` flags.  If you need Boost 1.40, you can still rebuild the current Debian unstable package.

Comment: I did not use this because it will put boost in my main drive, which I am running out of space.  So I compile/install boost in my external hard drive (which has much more space than my main drive).

Answer (score 3):

To save everybody's time, here's the answer I gave to this question elsewhere:
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/54626

Update 2016-02-11: It is necessary to specify the options directly:

```
g++ -I<prefix>/include -L <prefix>/lib
```

or use the right variables:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=<prefix>/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=<prefix>/lib
```

Comment: Kindly add the required part of answer here instead of putting link

Comment: This is question from 2009, related to Ubuntu 9.10. Lots of things have changed, and in particular Boost build process prints, at the end, instructions on using the installed Boost. May I suggest that if you have an issue as of now, you post a separate detailed question? Both the problem and solution might very well be different from what it was in this question.

Answer (score 0):

try C_INCLUDE_PATH or use -I compiler option

BTW, use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to help find library

Comment: I have set the C_INCLUDE_PATH and CPLUS_PATH, but I still get linking error:
: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'


I have set $ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/media/data/bin/boost/lib:

Comment: you have to specify library to link to with "-lXXX" flag, make sure you do not have space.of course you will have to replace XXX with the name of the library minus "lib" prefix and without suffix. i do not know the exact library name, you may have to read documentation.
LD variable specifies the search path for libraries, but not the library to link to.

Comment: you know what, just try adding -lboost to your compilation/linking command

Answer (score 0):

Check that headers is actually there:

/media/data/bin/boost/include/boost/bind.hpp

Also try using -I/media/data/bin/boost/include instead of env variable (notice no space after -I).